# changing color of specific word using Pages in macOS?

Tags: mac, macros, colors, iwork-pages

How can I change the color of specific word using Pages?

I just want to change the color of O and X of the already completed document. I don't really want the color to change immediately as I type.

I want to change the color of `O` and `X` text to corresponding colors.

- `O`: Blue.
- `X`: Red.

All of this needs to be done in Pages in macOS and I would like it to look like this.

> [image]

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: So do you want the color to change when you type? Or if any individual `O` or `X` shows up the color changes?

Comment: I just want to change the color of O and X of the already completed document. I don't really want the color to change immediately as I type.